# how to move back from form4 to form1?

Tags: c#, winforms

in my C# program i Moves from one screen to another like this:

```
Form G = new Screen1();
G.ShowDialog();
G.Dispose();
G.Close();
```

i move from screen1 -->  screen2  --> screen3  --> screen4

when i in **screen4**  and  i want to go back to **screen1** - if i'll write `this.close()`

i'll go only to **screen3**

how to go back from **screen4  to screen1**

thank's in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to close Form4 and get into Form1 in Windows mobile ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083984/how-to-close-form4-and-get-into-form1-in-windows-mobile)

Comment: your G.Close actually calls your Dispose, not sure if you were aware...

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a Wizard style approach.  There are a number of articles on how to do this on codeproject.com.  I've had luck with this one:

[Wizard Form Implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/WizardForm.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since all your form are modal (ShowDialog), adding a `this.Close();` after each call to Dispose on the child screen will close the direct parent:

```
Form G = new Screen1();
G.ShowDialog();
G.Dispose();
G.Close();
this.Close();
```

But you have to do this on screen2 and screen3.

You could also implement a class that will manage the opening and closing of child screens instead of doing it in each screen. This approach works well if you can chain the screens as some sort of wizard.

Comment: but with this solution i cant go back from form3 to form2  - or from form4 to form3....